# rio.plot.show with colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, rasterio

How can I add a colorbar after using rio.plot.show?
I've tried a bunch of things but have gotten various errors

Here's one way I tried:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (16, 16))

retted = rio.plot.show(ds, ax=ax, cmap='Greys_r')  

fig.colorbar(retted, ax=ax)
plt.title("Original")
plt.show()
```

This has error: `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_array'`

Comment: I guess a workaround would be to plot with `i = ax.imshow(ds, cmap='Greys_r')` then  cover this with the rio plot and finally add the colorbar `plt.colorbar(i)`

Answer (score 9):

I did what [david](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5539707/david) suggested above and it worked!

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))

# use imshow so that we have something to map the colorbar to
image_hidden = ax.imshow(image_data, 
                         cmap='Greys', 
                         vmin=-30, 
                         vmax=30)

# plot on the same axis with rio.plot.show
image = rio.plot.show(image_data, 
                      transform=src.transform, 
                      ax=ax, 
                      cmap='Greys', 
                      vmin=-30, 
                      vmax=30)

# add colorbar using the now hidden image
fig.colorbar(image_hidden, ax=ax)
```

Comment: Nice formatting. And you gave credit to David. Very good job for your first answer. I don't have time at the moment to test your solution, so I can't comment on correctness.

Comment: @Marjeta I had the same problem of the OP. I tested this answer and it works. According to this page https://sigon.gitlab.io/post/2018-11-08-plot-raster-nodata-values/ it seems to me the colorbar was added by default...

Comment: I had stumbled upon this solution while trying different things. Stumbled on to this answer while exploring if there is a more elegant solution. This seems to be the only way to do it for now.

Comment: Note that if the raster is rotated, then the current code will plot the rotated image on top of the non rotated (and not hidden anymore) image. I tumbled into this problem and solved it by adding `image_hidden.set_visible(False)`

Answer (score 6):

Different objects are returned by plt.imshow() and rasterio.plot.show(). plt.colorbar() is expecting a mappable object so it gets confused. Because rasterio plotting is a wrapper over matplotlib, I think the most straightforward approach is to provide the underlying object maptlotlib is expecting.

```
retted = rio.plot.show(ds, ax=ax, cmap='Greys_r')
im = retted.get_images()[0]
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with this solution, but I'd add that if you're like me, I usually have a `rasterio datasetreader` object (the result of reading in georeffed raster data with `rasterio.open`), not just a raw numpy array. So with rasterio v1.1.8 I have to do the extra step of extracting the numpy array from the datasetreader object. So for example, with a single band:

```
dem = rasterio.open("GIS/anaPlotDEM.tif")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
image_hidden = ax.imshow(dem.read()[0])
fig.colorbar(image_hidden, ax=ax)
rasterio.plot.show(dem, ax=ax)
```

(I'd add this as a comment but don't have the reputation points)

Answer (score 0):

If the data use different coordinate system. When you add the hidden image, you changed the x-axis and y-axis. Add the following code will solve:

```
# set the plot boundary to data.bounds
ax.set_xlim(data.bounds.left, data.bounds.right)
ax.set_ylim(data.bounds.bottom, data.bounds.top)
```